# How to see the Logs of Node js Server in Linux When running in background (Vs Code is Closed)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

1. I have created a node js server and it is running on the localhost:3000
2. Now i closed the vscode window where i was able to see the logs of api requests.
3. After Closing vscode windows the node js server is running in background.
4. now i reopen vscode, but cannot see the logs of the currently running server in the integrated terminal of the vscode (whereas i can make requests).

Is there any way to get the logs of the node js server which is running in the background ?
If no then how can I Stop the node js server running on localhost:3000

How to see the Logs of the Node js Server running in the background in Linux.

Comment: just redirect nodejs output to a file?

Comment: What I would do is to kill the server process from your OS process manager and restart the server from a new terminal. If you are not steaming the output of the server to any log file, you can't access the process output since the terminal that was displaying that info is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the user started the Node.js server in the background using the & symbol or a process manager like pm2 or forever, the logs would not be visible in the integrated terminal of VS Code even if they didn't close the terminal window.

In that case, the user can try accessing the logs directly from the log files. If the user didn't specify a log file path while starting the server, they can check the default log file location in the Node.js documentation for the logging library they are using.

To stop the Node.js server running on localhost:3000, the user can press Ctrl+C in the terminal window where the server was started, or they can use a process manager like pm2 or forever to stop the server.

Comment: they said "_Now i closed the vscode window where i was able to see the logs of api requests._" and then you said "_If you started the Node.js server in the background using the & symbol or by using a process manager like pm2 or forever, then the logs will not be visible in the integrated terminal of VS Code._"

Comment: Sorry. You're correct, I misread the question. If the user started the Node.js server in the background using the & symbol or a process manager like pm2 or forever, the logs would not be visible in the integrated terminal of VS Code even if they didn't close the terminal window.

Comment: In that case, the user can try accessing the logs directly from the log files. If the user didn't specify a log file path while starting the server, they can check the default log file location in the Node.js documentation for the logging library they are using.

Comment: To stop the Node.js server running on localhost:3000, the user can press Ctrl+C in the terminal window where the server was started, or they can use a process manager like pm2 or forever to stop the server.

Comment: you should edit clarifications into your answer post isntead of spamming the comments with clarifications.